# Enabling button if textboxes correct

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have three textboxes:

Username
Email
Password

Using JavaScript I have performed some regex's and some standard checking on all textboxes to check if the inputted text is correct according to my standards, here is my code so far:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username_txt" runat="server" placeholder="Username" maxlength="15" onkeyup="checkUsername(this.value)"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="username_lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>

asp:TextBox ID="email_txt" runat="server" placeholder="Email Address" onkeyup="checkEmail(this.value)"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="email_lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="password_txt" type="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="20" onkeyup="countPassword(this.value)" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="password_lbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<asp:Button ID="register_btn" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="register_btn_Click" />


function countPassword(password)
    {
        password_txt = document.getElementById('<%= password_txt.ClientID %>');
        password_lbl = document.getElementById('<%= password_lbl.ClientID %>');
        register_btn = document.getElementById('<%= register_btn.ClientID %>');

        if (password.length < 6)
        {
            password_lbl.innerHTML = 'Password must be at least 6 characters';
            password_lbl.style.color = "red";
            password_txt.style.outline = "1px solid red"
        }
        else
        {
            password_lbl.innerHTML = 'Perfect!';
            password_lbl.style.color = "green";
            password_txt.style.outline = "1px solid green"
        }
    }

function checkEmail(email)
    {
        email_lbl = document.getElementById('<%= email_lbl.ClientID %>');
        email_txt = document.getElementById('<%= email_txt.ClientID %>');
        register_btn = document.getElementById('<%= register_btn.ClientID%>');

        if (email == '') {
            email_lbl.innerHTML = 'Email cannot be blank';
            email_lbl.style.color = "red";
            email_txt.style.outline = "1px solid red"

        }
        else if (!email.match(/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/))
        {
            email_lbl.innerHTML = 'You must enter a valid email address';
            email_lbl.style.color = "red";
            email_txt.style.outline = "1px solid red"
        }
        else
        {
            email_txt.style.outline = "1px solid green"
            email_lbl.innerHTML = 'Perfect';
        }
    }

function checkUsername(username)
    {
        username_lbl = document.getElementById('<%= username_lbl.ClientID %>');
        username_txt = document.getElementById('<%= username_txt.ClientID %>');
        register_btn = document.getElementById('<%= register_btn.ClientID %>');

        if(username == '')
        {
            username_lbl.innerHTML = 'Username must be at least 4 characters';
            username_lbl.style.color = "red";
            username_txt.style.outline = "1px solid red"
        }
        else
        {
            username_txt.style.outline = "1px solid green"
            username_lbl.innerHTML = 'Perfect';
        }

     }
```

Now the problem I am having is that I need the register button to be enabled if all 3 of the textboxes reach the 'else' statements within each one of their keyup functions. However if 2 of the textboxes reach the else statements but 1 doesn't then the register button will remain disabled.

I am just struggling with the logic on how to achieve this, because I can't make another keyup event for each one of the textboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running the validation for each function individually, you could run ALL the functions in a single function called "validate". In each individual function, you would return true if the function validated successfully. If all values were true, then you set the register button true (enabled). If one of them is false, then set the register false (disabled).

```
function checkValidation() {
 var passcheck = countPassword();
 var emailCheck = checkEmail();
 var usernamecheck = checkUsername();
 if(passcheck && emailCheck && usernamecheck) {
   // set register true
 } else {
   // set register false
 }
}
```

I would probably use a library to take care of these functions though, as there are likely areas you will miss validating.

Comment: True, but that would require 3 parameters in the function which would make it harder to determine which textbox has entered data?

Comment: If you mean passing through the values, you could check the values via their element value rather than passing through the value into the function. So check password by document.getElementById("password_txt") etc. for each one.

Comment: Is their not another way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: You're trying to achieve basic validation, which again, I would probably use a library for to encapsulate all the varied difficulties you'll encounter with validation. They are reasonably easy to implement and take care of what you are doing with validation (email, name length, disabling elements, etc.).

Comment: The only problem with your way is that it will be checking validation for fields that haven't been touched yet. For example, if i entered in username textbox it will call this function which will check the password textbox in which the password textbox will be empty because I haven't reached that yet so then it'll display a message to the user. This is what I don't want happening

Comment: Aha, and now you're seeing why most of us use a validation engine ;) What you just mentioned would be something like making sure a validation isn't run until the field is touched at least once.